# "Lines have stretched around the block for days."

Tags: sentence-meaning

This is from [a *TIME* article](https://time.com/6158182/vitalik-buterin-ethereum-profile/).

> In a few minutes, electronic music will start pulsing, stuffed animals
> will be flung through the air, women will emerge spinning Technicolor
> hula hoops, and a mechanical bull will rev into action, bucking off
> one delighted rider after another. It’s the closing party of
> ETHDenver, a weeklong cryptocurrency conference dedicated to the
> blockchain Ethereum. **Lines have stretched around the block** for days.
> Now, on this Sunday night in February, the giddy energy is peaking.

My sense is that the part in bold means many people crowded around the block where the conference was held.

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "line" is a "queue" of people, waiting to get it.  Unlike a "crowd", a line of people has a distinct order to it.  And "around the block" means that the queue was very long.

At popular events, people will start queuing early, in order to be sure of getting in and getting a good position.  However I suspect that this is exaggeration. The use of a plural "lines" may also be exaggeration, or there may be several entrances (and so several "lines")

Generally "queue" = British English, and "line" = American.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: American: get in line! British: join the queue!

Comment: Thank you very much.